# Noob on HTML/PHP implode(): Invalid arguments passed in ~~

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new to html, mysql and php stuffs and I need some help :(

On html I created a 3 check boxes and named them as "userTime[]"

```
<label for = "day">Day Time (12:00~16:00)</label>
<input id = "day" type = "checkbox" value = "Day" name ="userTime[]"></br>

<label for = "dinner">Dinner (16:00~20:00)</label>
<input id = "dinner" type = "checkbox" value = "Dinner" name ="userTime[]"></br>

<label for = "night">Night (20:00~)</label>
<input id = "night" type = "checkbox" value = "Night" name ="userTime[]"></br>
```

Then I created a database through phpMyadmin and configured a row of userTime as type: varchar(10).
I wanted to have all the checked values in my database, so I tried

```
  $userTime = implode(',',$_POST['userTime']);
  $sql = "insert into member (userTime) values ('$userTime')";
```

however this keeps on giving me error: **implode(): Invalid arguments passed in ~~**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: echo `$userTime`

Comment: where is your `<form>` Tag and `<input type="submit">` button

Comment: If someone checks all three and you do an `implode()` on them (turning them into one single string), that string will be too long to fit in a varchar(10) since it would be 16 chars long.

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input.

Comment: When do you see that? When you load the page or when you submit the form? Are you sure it's posted correctly? We are a bit blind here since we don't see or know anything about the context of the posted code snippets. Also, if none of those checkboxes are checked, then `$_POST['userTime']` will be undefined. Checkboxes are only submitted if they are checked, otherwise they are completely omitted from the request.

Comment: my <form> Tag (<form action = "join.php" method = "post">) is above the the paragraph and the fieldset of the above code and <input type = "submit"> button is below the fieldset

Comment: I see the above code when I submit the form
I also tried 
```
$userTime = implode(',', (array)$_POST['userTime']);
```
Then It does work without any error but it would only save the last checkbox I check

Answer (score 1):

You should first validate the `$_POST['userTime']` if it is an array or not, because the second parameter in implode() must be an array

You can try this

```
if(is_array($_POST['userTime'])){
    $userTime = implode(',',$_POST['userTime']);
    $sql = "insert into member (userTime) values ('$userTime')";
} else {
    // Handle Error
}
```

Reference: [PHP Manual - Implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: Hi. Does the HTML code (`name ="userTime[]"`) not validate `$_POST['userTime']` as an array?

Comment: No, html code runs in the client. so the validation in the client is not the same as the backend. Make sure the `method="POST"` is set in the form tag

Comment: You can debug your code using `var_dump($_POST)` and see if the form was sent correctly

Comment: Just a tip. You can add a hidden input tag `<input type="hidden" name="userTime[]">` somewhere inside your form tag because if the non of the checkboxes were checked it will send userTime[] as undefined not an array